# Google Colab import DataBase from Kaggle

Tags: python, database, pandas, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Is it possible to upload data to colab from kaggle without downloading the csv file? And if possible, how would the import be done?

I say this because whenever I want to import a csv file I have to upload it, I want to save that step

Comment: You can do it using Kaggle API, For your reference- [https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-kaggle-in-google-colab-ebb281b61463](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-kaggle-in-google-colab-ebb281b61463)

Comment: https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api